# Search table for strings

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query where the whole table is searched for a string, in this case any string. The query should return rows where all the conditions are met. The database engine is InnoDB. `$keywordse` is an array which contains literal strings.
This is my code:

```
SELECT id, autorid, autor, date, longitude, latitude, title, text, town, time 
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH (title, text, town) AGAINST (" . implode(",",$keywordse) . ")
AND
(
    longitude >= $loo and longitude <= $lo

OR 
    latitude >= $laa and latitude <= $la 
) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear -- undefined variable. From the code you share, its not possible to determine how/when/if you defined it.

Comment: Yes youre right, I change that and now only the result of the shown query is undefinded.

Comment: "*I am trying to create a query*" -- Where are you constructing this query?  Your `WHERE` clause contains `...title, text, town LIKE...`; Is this even valid?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by this line in your query

```
WHERE * LIKE (" . implode(",",$keywordse) . ")
```

I doubt you can use operator * here.  Try to replace it with a field in which you're trying to find a string. Like autor, text or title in your case.

**UPDATED:**
There is FULLTEXT index in MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

After adding such index on the fields to your table you can easily search in multiple fields with

```
WHERE MATCH (title,autor,text) AGAINST ('keyword');
```

Comment: I want to search in every column for a string and thought * means in sql "all".

Comment: No it doesn't. MySQL does not support it. You need to list every field in the query.

Comment: I' ve changed it but nothing changed. :(

Comment: The condition should look like WHERE title LIKE '%keyword1%' OR title like '%keyword2%'

Comment: I have up to 8 keywords, is there no smarter way?

Comment: I try it with that, you can see it in my edit but it wont work too. :D